# Volume of fundamental domain in lattice of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-number-theory, convex-geometry

I'm trying to prove exercise 6.1 on *Algebraic number theory* by Stewart and Tall and essentially it states:

If $L$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with basis $u, v\in \mathbb{Z^2}$, $T$ its fundamental domain, i.e.
$$T=\{xu+yv: 0\leq x,y <1\}$$
and $n$ is the number of points of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that are in $T$ then
$$\operatorname{vol}(T)=n$$

I know Pick's theorem but the exercise is stated without any knowledge on that topic and I don't know how to prove it just knowing the definitions I gave. I've tried to prove it inductively on $n$ but I can't even prove the base case and I don't know how to relate in any way the volume and $n$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This exercise does not seem to be correct:  Take for example T = \Z^2, the standard integer lattice in \R^2.  By your definition of fundamental domain, the only lattice point in T would be the origin so n=1, but of course vol(T)=1 \not= n-2.

Comment: I mess it up, the $-2$ shouldn't be there. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm posting this as a separate answer to avoid cofusion with my previous reply).

The corrected form of your question is a simple consequence of Hermit normal form of integer matrices, aka row reduction.

Fix a basis $(u1, u2), (v1,v2)\in \mathbf Z^2$ of your sublattice, and consider the matrix
$
M = \bigl(
\begin{smallmatrix} 
  u1 & u2 \\
  v1 & v2 
\end{smallmatrix}
\bigr)
$.
To say that your sublattice has index n is to say that
$
\det(M)=n
$.
By row reduction over $\mathbf Z$, which is equivalent to mutiplying $M$ on the left by a matrix in $SL_2(\mathbf Z)$, we can turn $M$ into its unique Hermite normal form, i.e. a matrix of the form
$
H = \bigl(
\begin{smallmatrix} 
  a & b \\
  0 & d
\end{smallmatrix}
\bigr)
$
where $a, b, d\in \mathbf Z$ with $a|d$, and of course $ad=n$.  That means
$(a,b), (0,d)$ is a basis of your sublattice, and your exercise follows immediately (draw a picture).

Comment: I don't know if I don't understand something but row reduction is not equivalent to multiply on the left by a unimodular integer matrix. For example, if you consider $A= \bigl(
\begin{smallmatrix} 
  2 & 1 \\
  3 & 4
\end{smallmatrix}
\bigr)$ then by row reduction you get $A=UB$ where $B=\bigl(
\begin{smallmatrix} 
  6 & 3 \\
  0 & -5
\end{smallmatrix}
\bigr)$ and $U=\bigl(
\begin{smallmatrix} 
  3 & 0 \\
  3 & -2
\end{smallmatrix}
\bigr)$ and $U$ is not unimodular, so $(6,3), (0,-5)$ is not a base for the same lattice as the one with base $(2,1), (3,4)$

Comment: Thanks.   I meant to say "$\mathbf Z$-invertible row reduction", and I should change $SL_2(\mathbf Z)$ to $GL_2(\mathbf Z)$  (although with a tiny bit more care we can insist that the determinant be positive).

Comment: (for some reason I can't edit my comment above)  If the row reduction has determinant $-1$, it reverses the orientation of the basis and therefore turns the volume "negative", but of course that won't affect the lattice point count.

Comment: But to be a base of $L$, you should get $U$ the matrix you multiply by your $M$ to be in $SL_2(Z)$ and as I've shown with my example this is not always true.

Comment: "$\mathbf Z$-invertible" means that the matrix has an inverse with integer coefficents, and therefore has determinant $\pm 1$, i.e. in $GL_2(\mathbf Z)$.  The difference between $SL$ and $GL$ is orientation, which does not affect lattice point count and can be easier addressed with a tiny bit more care when carrying out the row reduction (but not needed for your problem).